# Multiprocess pool, with same function per 60 process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

So, the story. I have a list of accounts that I need do some filtering on them, more specifically.. there's a list of accounts on a specific website that holds many coins. I need to filter the balance of 2 million accounts.

So I want to process at least 100 accounts at a time. In the above example, that's what I tried.

```
max_proc =3

list_of_texts =[
    'acc_1',
    'acc_2',
    'acc_3',
    'acc_4',
    'acc_5',
    'acc_6',
    'acc_7',
    'acc_8',
    'acc_9',
    'acc_10',
    'acc_11',
]

def Start(text):
    print(text)

if __name__=='__main__':

    for index in range(0, len(list_of_texts), max_proc):

        pool = Pool(processes=max_proc)

        for item in list_of_texts[index:index+max_proc]:
            pool.map(Start, [item])
```

However I can't manage to make it work how I want, is still not parallel. My above example should have started 3 processes, with the first 3 accounts from the list, finish the.. then again process more 3 accounts until the list is done.
But all in parallel.
But it's still not working parallel, it's processing acc_1, then processing acc_2

The max_proc=3 is just for test, i will use 60 in production.

How I can achieve what I want?

Comment: You want to process at least 100 accounts at a time. Do you mean to have one process per account? That's a lot of processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your list in set of 3 and then run map over that part like this

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
max_proc =3

def start_fun(text):
    print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_of_texts =[
    'acc_1',
    'acc_2',
    'acc_3',
    'acc_4',
    'acc_5',
    'acc_6',
    'acc_7',
    'acc_8',
    'acc_9',
    'acc_10',
    'acc_11',
    ]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_proc) as pool:
        pool.map(start_fun, zip(*(iter(gen_of_texts),) * max_proc)) # to split list in groups of max_proc
```

### using imap

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
max_proc =300

def start_fun(text):
    return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_texts = ('GDUI73F5LZA47F4CBUNDT7FLWJ4U6DJQHDU3N3L55AONLUFV2QANT5D4' for _ in range(10**6))
    with Pool(max_proc) as pool:
        for res in pool.imap(start_fun, zip(*(iter(list_of_texts),) * max_proc), chunksize=max_proc):
            print(res)
```

Comment: not work, it crash

Comment: What's the error ? can you share the traceback .

Comment: Ther's no error, it simply stops. So right now, i have 250.000 accounts in list..   I started  max_proc = 50   of 1000 accounts each proc,  it simply stops without any error.. it stops execution

Comment: Can you show me your code how you are using because i tried my code on my system with 10**6 values list and it worked fine.

Comment: Also is your list is bulky in size because if that's the case then use imap instead of map, I will edit the changes.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, code is too big to post here..  I put on pastebin in few moments

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s7TTWEeH Full code of script, u can handle the install of packages

Comment: Here are wallets.txt file https://pastebin.com/Y0Hmw4T5  there are just 1k records, because limit of pastebin...  u can duplicate this 1000 records many times/

Comment: Simply use that script, use what's in wallets.txt

Comment: I was able to run my code using your pastebin code, check my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You've overcomplicated your code.

Consider this:-

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

max_proc = 3

list_of_texts =[
    'acc_1',
    'acc_2',
    'acc_3',
    'acc_4',
    'acc_5',
    'acc_6',
    'acc_7',
    'acc_8',
    'acc_9',
    'acc_10',
    'acc_11',
]

def Start(text):
    print(text)

if __name__=='__main__':
    with Pool(processes=max_proc) as pool:
        pool.map(Start, list_of_texts)
```

Because of the pool size (3) there will be at most 3 concurrent processes. Each process will handle a single value - e.g., 'acc_1'

Comment: it's not working well, it executes just one by one.  What I want is to process a set of texts at the same time.. Example, start 60 processes  and each process to process 100 accounts( texts)